# How to keep the aspect ratio of the image in css?

Tags: css, image, aspect-ratio

How to keep the aspect ratio of the image in css?

```
#prodImg {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

the problem is i have my images in different aspect ration and i only want it to be rectangular orientation and responsive.

Comment: Please use the search feature before posting questions that have already been answered. Otherwise, glad we could help you with your question. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#prodImg {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```